# Find set of points of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ which are not isolated.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

1. Consider the topological space $(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}, <)$, consisting of set $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ with the dictionary order topology. Find the set of points of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ which are not isolated.

Hello, I am confused on how to approach this problem and any guidance and explanation on how to solve it is highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume $\mathbb{N}$ to contain $0$, if it is to be considered without, then just replace every $0$ by a $1$ in the following. Also I'm too lazy to type $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ every time, so I will just call it $X$.

The order topology is generated by the subbasis given by the rays, i.e. for every point $a\in X$ the sets $\{x\in X\colon a<x\}$ and $\{x\in X\colon x<a\}$ are open and we have finite intersections and arbitrary unions of these sets. In particular, a basis of the topology is given by the intervals, i.e. every open set is a union of sets of the form $\langle a,b\rangle := \{x\in X\colon a<x<b\}$ for $a,b\in X$.

(Sorry for the abuse of notation using pointy brackets but normal parantheses would get confusing with pair notation...)

Now the answer to the question comes down to a case-distinction for $(n,m)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. If you are just looking for tips, you probably should not read further but actually attempt it yourself.

If $n=m=0$: $\{(0,0)\}$ is open, because it is the set $\{x\in X\colon x<(0,1)\}$ and hence is a set in the subbasis.

If $m\neq 0$, then $\{(n,m)\}$ is equal to the set $\{x\in X\colon (n,m-1)<x<(n,m+1)\}$, which is open (a base set).

However, this construction fails if $m=0$. Indeed, given an element of the form $(n,0)$, the set $\{x\in X\colon x<(n,0)\}$ consists precisely of the elements $(a,b)$, where $a<n$. Intuitively, this set does not have a maximal element, hence there should not be a lower bound to isolate the point $(n,0)$. Let's prove this:

We want to show that $(n,0)$ is not isolated, i.e. every open set containing $(n,0)$ also contains another point. Let $O$ be any open set containing $(n,0)$. Because the intervals form a basis, $O$ contains an interval of the form $\langle a,b\rangle$ where $a<(n,0)$ and $(n,0)<b$. As we have stated before, by the lexicographic ordering, if $a<(n,0)$, it must be of the form $a=(a_1,a_2)$ with $a_1<n$. Now, the element $(a_1, a_2 + 1)$ is larger than $a$, but still smaller than $(n,0)$, hence also a member of $O$. (More generally: Every element of the form $(a_1,c)$, where $c>a_2$ fulfills the same condition, i.e. is contained in $O$).

In summary: The set of non-isolated points is $\{(n,0)\vert n\in\mathbb{N}, n>0\}$.

Hope that helps, if there are any questions, just ask. =)

Comment: Thank you for your time and help with this. I was confused and still learning/studying Munkree's text.